# Using sqrt() funtion in switch case

Tags: c++, calculator

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
 using namespace std;
  int main(void)
 {
   float a,b,y,z,x;
   char chart;

 cout<< "Enter Operator";
 cin>>chart;
 cout<<"\n\t Enter First Number\n";
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"\n\t Enter Second Number\n";
 cin>>b;
 switch (chart) 
    {
     case '+':
        a+b;
         cout<<"\n\t"<<a+b<<"\n";
         break;

    case '-':
        cout<<"\n\t"<<a-b<<"\n";
        break;
    
    case '*' :
        cout<<"\n\t"<<a*b<<"\n";
        break;

   case '/':
       cout<<"\n\t"<<a/b<<"\n";
       break;            

     default:
         cout<< " \nThe operator is not supported\n\n\n\n\n";
         break;
    }


   return 0;}
```

I am a beginner and new to C++ ]. this is my code for a simple calculator, I want to know how to use the    sqrt()    funtion in switch case. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. Also please suggest how to make this code better

Comment: You type `sqrt(` and then the expression you want to take the square root of, followed by `)`

Comment: Your calculator only supports binary operations. as in dual-valued, and square-root is not such an operation. It is "unary" as in "takes one number".

Comment: On SO, please make sure to describe your problem **before** you post your code snippet. On that point, also make sure to make a minimal reproducible example, and very little more.

Comment: Your `a+b;` statement is worthless.  It doesn't change any variables; it doesn't print.  The compiler may remove it depending on the optimization level.  The idea is that the sum is calculated, then discarded since you are not assigning the sum to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one little bit modified on the basis of unary and binary operators you can also alter it according to your need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int op;
    cout << "Enter 1 for unary operation or 2 for binary operation: ";
    cin >> op;
    if (op==1)
    {
        int operation;
        int num;
        cout << "\nEnter number: ";
        cin >> num;
        cout << "\nEnter number 1 to perform square root: ";
        cin >> operation;
        if (operation==1)
            cout << "\n\t" << sqrt(num) << "\n";
        else
            cout << " \nThe operator is not supported\n\n\n\n\n";
    }
    else if (op==2)
    {
        char chart;
        float a, b;
        cout << "\n\t Enter First Number\n";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "\n\t Enter Second Number\n";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "\n\t Enter the binary operator\n";
        cin >> chart;
        switch (chart) 
        {
            case '+':
                cout << "\n\t" << a+b << "\n";
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << "\n\t" << a-b << "\n";
                break;
            case '*' :
                cout << "\n\t" << a*b << "\n";
                break;
            case '/':
                cout << "\n\t" << a/b << "\n";
                break;            
            default:
                cout << " \nThe operator is not supported\n\n\n\n\n";
                break;
         }
    }
    else
        cout << " \nThe operator is not supported\n\n\n\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).